# How can I toggle all my Bootstrap Popovers by clicking on another button?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some Bootstrap Popover Buttons:

```
<div class="bs-example tooltip-demo">
    <div class="bs-example-tooltips">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">Popover on top</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">Popover on bottom</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">Popover on right</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
   <button id="toggle" class="btn btn-default" >Toggle all</button>
```

Here the script:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();


$('#toggle').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {

        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('toggle');
        }
    });
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {

        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

So what I want to achieve is:

- By click on the Popover Buttons itself: Do nothing (No Popover)
- By click on `Toggle all` toggle all Popovers
- By click on the body hide all Popovers

In my code it is not working, maybe there is a conflict with the hide and toggle?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/1421/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the last button to toggle all of the popovers on the page, then this is all you need to do:

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');
});
```

Also this code will hide all popovers if you click on anything that isn't a popover or the button that toggles the popovers:

```
$('html').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if(typeof $(e.target).data('toggle') === "undefined" 
       && $(e.target).attr('id') != 'toggle') {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Your fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/1426/

Comment: Hello, thank you! No this is not the last button, and also if I click on the popover buttons itself I do not want a popover, only by clicking on "toggle all"

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not the last button", it's really not clear. To prevent a button from showing it's own popover, just add a trigger value of manual (e.g. `data-trigger="manual"`)

Comment: Well you assumed that I want the last button to toggle. But this is not the case. My button `toggle all` is not the last button on the page. To make this clear: https://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/1425/

Comment: No I assumed you want the button titled "toggle all" to toggle all the popovers because your question says "By click on `Toggle all` toggle all Popovers".

Comment: `data-trigger="manual"`Thank you! This is what I was looking for

Comment: Ah ok, this was a misunderstanding than, yes I want ONLY `toggle all` to toggle anything, not the buttons itself, and by clicking the body hide everything again

Comment: Try the update, I think it does everything you need.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you very much for the help

Comment: I have just one question, maybe you know the reason, in the fiddle it works very well but when I use the same code on my website the toggle on the `#toggle` button only works one time. With the second click it is not working anymore. Only if I click on the body and everything hides, the `#toggle` button works for one time again

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to tell from here.